# cannot get human readable text from various functions discovered

Tags: php, date, unix-timestamp

I am trying to `transform a unix timestamp into a human readable string so i can show how long ago a user signed up`.

Here is my data:

```
    mysql> select createdate as unixtimestamp,date_format(from_unixtime(createdate),'%e %b %Y') as dateformatted from users where userid=40645;
    +---------------+---------------+
    | unixtimestamp | dateformatted |
    +---------------+---------------+
    |    1162642968 | 4 Nov 2006    |
    +---------------+---------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
    mysql>
```

Ok so here is where the problem resides. I found 3 different functions on the internet that return a human readable string from a unix timestamp. **All 3 failed to work**.

**I'd like someone to look at these functions and help me figure out how to fix one of them to return the correct human readable string.**

On with the show!

Here is function #1:

```
    function getElapstedTimeHumanReadable($time)
    {
    $names = array("seconds", "minutes", "hours", "days", "months", "years");
    $values = array(1, 60, 3600, 24 * 3600, 30 * 24 * 3600, 365 * 24 * 3600);
    $time = time()-$time;
    for($i = count($values) - 1; $i > 0 && $time < $values[$i]; $i--);
    if($i == 0) {
        $timestamp = intval($time / $values[$i]) . " " . $names[$i];
    } else {
        $t1 = intval($time / $values[$i]);
        $t2 = intval(($time - $t1 * $values[$i]) / $values[$i - 1]);
        $timestamp= "$t1 " . $names[$i] . ", $t2 " . $names[$i - 1];
    }
    return $timestamp;
    }
```

**My return value for this function is "Joined 1 days, 17 hours ago"**

**Clearly this isn't correct.**

Here is function #2:

```
    function getElapsedTimeHumanReadable($time)
    {
     $time = time() - $time;
     $points = array(
        'year'     => 31556926,
        'month'    => 2629743,
        'week'     => 604800,
        'day'      => 86400,
        'hour'     => 3600,
        'minute'   => 60,
        'second'   => 1
    );
    foreach($points as $point => $value)
    {
        if($elapsed = floor($time/$value) > 0)
        {
            $s = $elapsed>1?'s':'';
            $timestamp = "$elapsed $point$s";
            break;
        }
    }
    return $timestamp;
    }
```

**My return value for this function is "Joined 1 day ago**

And finally, here is function #3:

```
    function getElapsedTimeHumanReadable($time)
    {
    $etime=time()-$time;
    if ($etime < 1)
    {
        return '0 seconds';
    }

    $a = array( 365 * 24 * 60 * 60  =>  'year',
             30 * 24 * 60 * 60  =>  'month',
                  24 * 60 * 60  =>  'day',
                       60 * 60  =>  'hour',
                            60  =>  'minute',
                             1  =>  'second'
            );
    $a_plural = array( 'year'   => 'years',
                   'month'  => 'months',
                   'day'    => 'days',
                   'hour'   => 'hours',
                   'minute' => 'minutes',
                   'second' => 'seconds'
            );

    foreach ($a as $secs => $str)
    {
        $d = $etime / $secs;
        if ($d >= 1)
        {
            $r = round($d);
            return $r . ' ' . ($r > 1 ? $a_plural[$str] : $str) . ' ago';
        }
    }
    }
```

So theres my code and my data. **Not quite sure why none seem to work. I tried looking at the code but I cannot figure out how to solve it.**

`Whats interesting is they all say 2 days, but my timestamp appears to show 2006.`

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$time = 1162642968 ;
$date = new DateTime( );
$date->setTimestamp( $time );
$today = new DateTime( 'now', new DateTimeZone( "Europe/Rome" ) );
$diff = $today->diff( $date);
echo "Year: " . $diff->y . " - Month: " . $diff->m . " - Days: " . $diff->d . " - Hours: " . $diff->h;
```

[EXAMPLE](https://eval.in/472084)

As suggested I'll add explanation, even if I think it is really self explain.

$date = new DateTime() create the object and $date->setTimestamp( $time ) is used to put that date at a value from the mysql timestamp.

$today is created pointing at the actual date.

$date->diff() create a DateInterval Object ( http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php ) that contains all the necessary datas.

Comment: Add some explanation not just code. Also could use `echo $diff->format('%y years %m months %d days');`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve this yourself, you should calculate the difference and base it on those values. I haven't tested RiccardoC's Answer, but this seems as a nice way to go.

As I see in your posting, you calculate a year always as 365 days, so if you don't want to go in a deep detail with time zones, extra hours, extra days, different month lengths etc, you could use something simple as that:

```
function getElapsedTimeHumanReadable($timestamp) { 
    $diff = time() - $timestamp;
    $years = intval($diff/31536000); //seconds in a year 60*60*24*365
    $diff -= ($years*31536000);
    $months = intval($diff/2592000); //seconds in a month 60*60*24*30
    $diff -= ($months*2592000);
    $days = intval($diff/86400); //seconds in a day 60*60*24
    return $years." years, ".$months." months, ".$days." days ago";
}
echo getElapsedTimeHumanReadable(1162642968); // November 4th, 2006
```

Echos `9 years, 0 months, 17 days ago`

Comment: This do not take in account bissextiles